# How to call usernames and password from fixture file into test scenario in Cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I have my login test scenario which is working. I have removed my username and password to a fixture file, which I then want to call in order to populate the username and password fields. Can someone point me in the right direction of how this should be done? Below is my test scenario tyring to call the fixture to populate the fields

```js
describe('My Login Test', function (){
it('Visit Risk App Landing Page', function (){
cy.visit('site url')
cy.get('button').click()
cy.get('a.auth0-lock-alternative-link').contains('Not your account?').click()
cy.get('input.auth0-lock-input').first()
.type(cy.fixture('loginUser').email)
cy.get('input.auth0-lock-input').last()
.type(cy.fixture('loginUser').password)
cy.get('button').click()
cy.url().should('eq','site url')
})
})
```

Comment: What is the error that you're having?

Answer (score 3):

I was given the answer by someone in a gitter chatroom:

```
describe('My Login Test', function (){
it('Visit Risk App Landing Page', function (){
    cy.visit('https://bvt-riskassessment.lmkcloud.net')
    cy.get('button').click()
    cy.get('a.auth0-lock-alternative-link').contains('Not your account?').click()
    cy.fixture('loginUser').as('myUserFixture');
    cy.get('@myUserFixture').then(user => {
    cy.get('input.auth0-lock-input').first().type(user.email);
    cy.get('input.auth0-lock-input').last().type(user.password);
    cy.get('button').click()
    cy.url().should('eq','https://bvt-riskassessment.lmkcloud.net/workflow')
```

I can now login using this without having the username or password in every test scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a fixture alias.

see: [Accessing-Fixture-Data](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture.html#Accessing-Fixture-Data)

First, create a local variable for the fixture:

`cy.fixture('loginUser').as('myUser');`

then, when you want to access it's properties, it's just `this.myUser.email` or something. This would change your test to:

`.type(this.myUser.email)`

Hopefully that will help with your problems? But, as demouser123 mentioned, we'd need the actual error in order to help you.

Comment: I'm getting different error when I try different methods, when I tries Stevens method:
        cy.get('input.auth0-lock-input').last()
        cy.fixture('loginUser').as('myUser').type(this.myUser.email)
The test doesn't run and I get this message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined"

Comment: Are you using "Fat Arrows"? Alias' require standard functions. ( I just ran into this the other day myself )

See: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1641

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `import` like this:

```
import jsonFile from '../../../fixtures/file.json'

describe('getting field from json', () => {
it('get something from json', () => {
        cy.get('input[name=inputField]').clear().type(jsonFile.myField)
    })
}
```

Where `file.json` is:

```
{
  "myField": "you can get it"
}
```